# Как можно разрешить этот знак?

Tags: php, mysql

```
 mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM `laptop` WHERE user = '$userdata['user_login']'"
```

Выдает ошибку в `$userdata['user_login']` а именно в одинарных кавычках. Можно ли это както разрешить?

Извините за корявое объяснение, надеюсь вы поймете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так:

```
"SELECT * FROM laptop WHERE user = '{$userdata['user_login']}'"
```

Подробно можно почитать в документации: **[Обработка переменных](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing)**

Comment: Ваш ответ очень сильно помог. Спасибо большое.